# MongoDB: Why does update() return null even when successful?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I'm using this code to insert (or update if already existing) a new user to the databse:

```
   emailAddress = self.request.params.get('emailaddress')
    googleRefreshToken = self.request.params.get('googlerefreshtoken')

    # upsert new user
    postData = {"emailAddress" : emailAddress,
        "googleRefreshToken" : googleRefreshToken}
    newPost = self.request.db.users.update( { 'emailAddress' : emailAddress }, postData, True );


    return json.dumps( newPost, default=json_util.default)
```

I'm assuming that update() should return the objects _id or even the object itself...but it always returns null even though the upsert works correctly. Why is it returning null and how can I get it to return the _id or object itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described in the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update), if you include `safe=True` in your parameters to `update`, the response to `lastError` is returned, otherwise it returns `None`.  If you want the `_id` of the document updated, you'll either have to query for it separately or use [`find_and_modify`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify) instead of `update`.

Comment: I did read the docs before I came here...I guess they were just unclear to me. Thanks for the answer.